# Cakephp CSV helper generating leading space

Tags: php, csv, cakephp

I'm creating a CSV file using CakePHP CSV helper.

I'm always getting one space at the beginning of the column. I have used `trim`, `ltrim` but nothing works.

I have also added `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean` but nothing works.

My CSV code is

```
  <?php

class CsvHelper extends AppHelper {

    var $delimiter = ',';
    var $enclosure = '"';
    var $filename = 'Export.csv';
    var $line = array();
    var $buffer;

    function CsvHelper() {
        $this->clear();
    }

    function clear() {
        $this->line = array();
        $this->buffer = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:' . (5 * 1024 * 1024), 'r+');
    }

    function addField($value) {
        $this->line[] = $value;
    }

    function endRow() {
        $this->addRow($this->line);
        $this->line = array();
    }

    function addRow($row) {

        fputcsv($this->buffer, $row, $this->delimiter, $this->enclosure);
    }

    function renderHeaders() {
        ob_start();
        header('Content-Encoding:  UTF-16LE');
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $this->filename . '"');
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    function setFilename($filename) {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        if (strtolower(substr($this->filename, -4)) != '.csv') {
            $this->filename .= '.csv';
        }
    }

    function render($outputHeaders = true, $to_encoding = null, $from_encoding = "auto") {

        if ($outputHeaders) {
            if (is_string($outputHeaders)) {

                $this->setFilename(trim($outputHeaders));
            }
            $this->renderHeaders();
        }

        rewind($this->buffer);
        $output = stream_get_contents($this->buffer);

        if ($to_encoding) {
            $output = mb_convert_encoding($output, $to_encoding, $from_encoding);
        }

        return $this->output(trim($output));
    }

}

?>
```

I'm calling this helper from this ctp file to download and generate report.

```
<?php
$line = $gen_reports[0]['Report'];
$arrayKeys = array_keys($line);

$this->CSV->addRow($arrayKeys);
echo $this->CSV->render("filename");die;
?>
```

and the result I'm getting always a leading space at the very first column:

[image: screenshot]

How can I get rid of this space?

Comment: Sounds like the BOM (byte order mark)?

Comment: Thanks mark, i read about this, so if this is the issue, how can i ignore this I'm using window OS

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if only a copy-paste error but you have an extra space right before your CsvHelper opening php tag which could result in a space in the output buffer.

Comment: Also beware extra spaces after php closing tag - better not use it if you really don't have to.

Comment: Space is removed from the php opening tag, and I also remove the closing tag but it doesn't work.
after the r&d i found may be that could be the issue of fputcsv function